# Changing one event listener to another?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and I was wondering if it s possible to change all click events (for elements within a specific div) to double click events using jquery? Many thanks in advance.

```
function isTouchDevice(){
  return (typeof(window.ontouchstart) != 'undefined') ? true : false;
}
if(isTouchDevice()===true){
     //change click events to doubleclick events
}
```

Comment: `(typeof(window.ontouchstart) != 'undefined') ? true : false;` is redundant. Use `(typeof(window.ontouchstart) !== 'undefined')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watch this magic:

```
$('*').each(function(){
   var click = $(this).data('events').click;
   if(click[0]) { //check if there is a click handler attached 
       $(this).on('dblclick', click[0].handler).off('click');
   }
});
```

The above will go through **every** element on the page and move it's click handler to its dblclick handler.

Using `*` is not usually advised. I would try just selecting all of the elemts that have a click selector instead and go through them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is it possible to replace hover events with click events as well? or does this accomplish this automatically?

Comment: @MHZ just follow what I have there in the code... but really what I would do is when you are **attaching** the events, I would just decide whether or not to use click or dblclick instead of using my hacky way...

Comment: Will adding if(hover[0]){ $(this).on('click', hover[0].handler).off('hover')} work to handle hovers as well? I appreciate the help :)

Comment: @MHZ lol no idea. just see what is in the events object and utilize it ^_^

Comment: FYI, `.data("events")` has been deprecated

Comment: @Alexander then what do you use instead?

Comment: @Neal +1 fair enough haha.

Comment: @Neal, allegedly `$._data(element, "events")`, but it doesn't seem clear if they are planning a long standing function for it. Anyways, you should [check out jQuery 1.8 changes](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/) yourself

Comment: @Alexander hehe im fine with 1.7.2 ^_^ i dont think i need the upgrade. It breaks things...

Comment: @Neal not working, I am getting the following error with your code: cannot read property click of undefined.

Comment: @MHZ what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @MHZ see Alexander's comment above.

Comment: @MHZ did you read the comment? use `$._data(element, "events")`

Comment: Yes I tried: `$._data($(this), "events").click;` and it generates the same error.

Comment: This guy just created [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14023792/417685) for it. It actually differs a bit since `hover` is a bit tricky and he got `$._data()` wrong

Answer (score 0):

Sure is...

```
function yourClickHandler(event) {
    // here you can check for click or dblclick as so...
    if (event.type == 'dblclick') { /* handle dblclick specific stuff */ }
    else if (event.type == 'click') { /* handle normal click specific stuff */ }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (isTouchDevice()) {
        $('div#SPECIFIC_DIV *').on('dblclick', yourClickHandler);
    }
    else {
        $('div#SPECIFIC_DIV *').on('click', yourClickHandler);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but now both click and dbl click will do the same thing.

Comment: Then why even have a 'click' event? Just add your 'dblclick' event handler and be done with it.

Comment: @Derek, what I am trying to do is, once a touch enabled device is detected, replace hover w/ tap, and click w/ doubletap.

Comment: The cleaner way would be to detect this before you even assign event handlers. Define the handler as a standalone function and then assign your click or dblclick handler to that based on your touch enabled detection.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('#target').click(function() {
    if(isTouchDevice == true) {
      $('#target').dblclick();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but now both click and dbl click will do the same thing.

Comment: Actually yeah, but in touch devices, the double click behavior is needed to click buttons.